# Is it possible to call a powershell script within another script as a variable?

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0

I have a Powershell script where the user passes in a script as a parameter. After that is passed in, I cannot call the script by using $scriptvariable. Is there any way to call a Powershell script from within another Powershell script, when the one script needs to be called from a variable.

```
param(
  [string]hostval,
  [string]$scriptpath
)

Invoke-Command -Computer $hostval -Scriptblock { $scriptpath } -credential $cred
```

This does not work, and I'm not sure if what I want is possible. Is there a parameter type (ex: [script]$scriptpath) that I can use so the script can be called from $scriptpath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the -FilePath parameter, instead of -Scriptblock:

```
-FilePath <String>
    Runs the specified local script on one or more remote computers. Enter the path and file name of the script, or pipe a script path to Invoke-Command. The script must reside on the local computer or in a directory that the local computer can access. Use the ArgumentList parameter to specify the values of parameters in the script.
```